# What do you call a monogram that consists of a single letter?

Tags: meaning

I am looking for a name for a single letter that is part of a bigger logo, but can also be used stand-alone.

Part of my logo uses a standalone "M" (my initial) and I want to use the correct term to describe it. Monogram seems to fit the bill mostly.

According to [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/monogram), a Monogram is either:

1. "a design consisting of two or more alphabetic letters combined or interlaced, commonly one's initials, often printed on stationery, embroidered on clothing, etc."
2. "a single emblematic or decorative letter; applied initial."

However, other sources explicitly state that a monogram consists of at least two initials.

Wikipedia suggests Varsity Letter, which is tied to USA high schools.
There is also "Grapheme," which appears to describe a single functional letter as opposed to a single decorative letter.

**Can you use Monogram to describe a single, decorative letter used as (part of a) logo?**

Comment: "correct" in what context? Applying for a trademark? Ordering stationery?

Comment: @TimR Using it to describe the item, in my case either as a definition ("This is a Monogram") and in a filename (e.g, `logo_monogram.png`)

Comment: Update: I have learned that logos can also use the term "brand mark" or "logo mark" to describe the emblem or symbolic logo version that does not contain the company name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/monogram) certainly licenses the single-letter variety, but interestingly adds the 'British English' caveat::

> **monogram** [British English] [noun]
>
> 1. a design of one or more letters, especially initials, embroidered on clothing, printed on stationery, etc

The 'American English' usage only licenses two-letter (or above) types (which are admittedly far more common):

> **monogram** [in American English] [noun]
>
> 1. a character or figure made up of two or more letters, often initials of a name, combined in a single design: used on writing
>    paper, ornaments, clothing, etc.

[The American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/monogram) seems to be the only other freely available online dictionary to allow the single-letter type (and adds no caveat). All others, including OALD and Cambridge Dictionary, require a combination of (usually initial) letters

To keep everybody on both sides of the Atlantic happy, I'd suggest that only pedants would object to 'single-letter monogram'. There may be fewer Anglophones in the UK, but they arguably have a better claim to the English language.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not consider US and British English having different requirements with regards to the number of letters in a monogram.

Comment: AHD is US-based and will probably use relevant corpora, and it allows the single-letter usage, so it's (as always) not a straight divide.

Comment: Yes, and let's also add that initials need two letters for most names. But what shall we do when our name is Cher, Madonna, Melanie, Prince, Sting?

Comment: The Man with No Name let his gun do all the talking, Yosef.

Comment: Is the artist formerly known as the artist formerly known as Prince's symbol (Ƭ̵̬̊) a monogram?

Comment: @Peter No, even then we had stereo.

Comment: @PeterShor — Here is the monogram of Christ: ☧ — the combination  of the first two letters of Greek Χριστός (*OED*).